# Android Studio com.android.gms:google-services:3.0.0 error

Tags: android, firebase, gradle

[image: Screenshot of my Android Studio screen]
So I have the .json file in my app folder, and followed all the instructions on the Firebase site, but I still get an error that says that AS can't find the google-services:3.0.0
Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have to download it via the Android SDK manager.

Comment: Do you have latest version of google play services ? Go to **SDK Manager** and see if there is any update.

Comment: @mallaudin I think i have the latest version of google play services, there aren't any updates in SDK Manager.

Comment: @JaredBurrows how would I download it via SDK manager? The firebase instructions told me to download it from their site and place the .json file in the app folder

Comment: @Bob mentioned, you have a typo in version name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's `com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0`, not `com.android.gms:google-services:3.0.0`.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'  // <= HERE

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```